# What is the term for when too many choices results in inability to decide?

Tags: terminology, decision-making, consumer-psychology

A common problem is that when offered too many choices, consumers give up and make *no* choice. Too many options results in no sale where fewer options might have resulted in more sales. It's like the cognitive load of so many choices makes the decision impossible.

I've heard it called Decision Paralysis or "[Analysis Paralysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis)" but these terms don't seem to have a root in cognitive science. Is there a formal or generally accepted term for this phenomenon?

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with the application of equal weights to all attributes/options, even when some are irrelevant. Whether a digital camera has a huge sensor or a miniscule sensor should be such a big factor that it outweighs whether the camera finish is glossy or matte black, but I think people have a difficult time rationally weighing these things. Likely, heuristically driven decision making probably assigns weights much more efficiently -- hence, the value of going with your gut!

Comment: @AndyDeSoto the presumption of equal weight is probably very relevant; related to scanning the ability to filter out irrelevant options is very important. If you can't it may simply seem like all options are valid or that none of them are.

Comment: [this RSA video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bqMY82xzWo) might be of interest.

Comment: related is [Buridan's Ass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buridan%27s_ass)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is "[paradox of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Paradox_of_Choice)". See these resources:

- [*The paradox of choice: why more is less* By Barry Schwartz](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=g422yyua-P8C&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=%22paradox+of+choice%22&ots=vyOzyHzzFf&sig=8SiCNH7NRJKZHeCnXjUJzIdg1xo) (Google Books)
- [Excerpts from the above book by Barry Schwartz](http://information-marketing.net/BrandingAdvertisingMarketing/Quotes/ParadoxOfChoice_Quotes.doc) (`.doc` format)
- [*Positive Psychology in Practice* chapter 6 *Doing Better but Feeling Worse:
  The Paradox of Choice* by Barry Schwartz and Andrew Ward](http://students.sfu.ca/health/mentalhealth/mentalhealthpapers/Hupper_2004.pdf#page=110) (`.pdf` format)

I actually haven't been able to find anything in my search just now, but I remember some claims about a year ago that recent experiments had suggested that the original results were somewhat over-blown.

Comment: I was additionally planning to ask a question about the significance of it, but I had to know what to call it first

Comment: A TED talk on paradox of choice: http://www.ted.com/talks/barry_schwartz_on_the_paradox_of_choice.html

Comment: +1, also known as "choice overload". william is right, though, that the original results may be overblown. see a meta-analysis @ http://www.scheibehenne.de/ScheibehenneGreifenederTodd2010.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Overchoice or "choice overload" are the common used terms for

> describing the cognitive process in which people have a difficult time making a decision when faced with many options (Wikipedia on Overchoice)

The same souce refers that the concept was first introduced by Alvin Toffler in his book named Future Shock.

Barry Schwartz as well as [Barbara Fasolo and collegues](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1470593107073842) call it "the tiranny of choice".

Nevertheless, recently, some authors have been cast doubts

> on the phenomenon being as pervasive or important as some might have given it credit for. Instead, it appears probable that such choice effects might be limited to particular contexts, assuming they reliably exist in the first place (see [Is Choice Overload a Real Thing?](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/pop-psych/201602/is-choice-overload-real-thing))

Answer (score 1):

In HCI terms, which is where I come from, this would probably be called information overload. It is the situation where a person is presented with so much information that they cannot process all of it successfully.

In Cognitive terms, the term probably works best because it is caused, I believe, by insufficient short term memory being available to successfully process what is needed from a page, so the decisions about what to do cannot be made. In a similar way, if too much information is given to a person - even if expressed in terms of "you could do this, or you could do this... " then they cannot dismiss the options enough to narrow it down. Without this, decisions cannot be made.

Comment: [Cognitive Load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_load) is certainly related but not quite specific enough. Cognitive load refers to any situation where WM is stressed, not just too many options halting the ability to make a decision